# Create a table to simulate a light animation using Java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a table like 
[exemple of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slA5W.png) to simulate a light animation.
The animation is, after a click on the start button, change
gradually the color of the tiles from left to right,
then from top to bottom using a list of ten colors
different.
Will Appreciate any help.

I have the code HTML and CSS, i need JS.

```js
function animation(){
    var colors = [
     "rgb(0,0,0)",
     "rgb(255,0,0)",
     "rgb(0,255,0)",
     "rgb(0,0,255)",
     "rgb(100,0,100)",
     "rgb(125,125,0)",
     "rgb(0,150,150)",
     "rgb(175,175,175)",
     "rgb(200,0,100)",
     "rgb(1,0,100)",
     "rgb(225,225,225)"
      ];
  
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table td div")).forEach(function(item, index){
 
     var color = colors[ index % 11 ];
    item.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}
```

```css
body { width: 450px; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
   
 }


table td { height: 45px; 
   width: 45px; 
   padding: 0em; 
   background-color:#F7F27F; 
   
 }
/*table {border-collapse: collapse;
}*/
 
table td div { height:100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out  ; 
     }



table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#B0090C; }
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) { background-color:#B0090C; }

table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 0.1s}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 0.2s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 0.3s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 0.4s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 0.5s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 0.6s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 0.7s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 0.8s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 0.9s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 1.0s }

table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 1.1s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 1.2s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 1.3s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 1.4s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 1.5s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 1.6s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 1.7s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 1.8s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 1.9s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 2.0s }



table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 2.1s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 2.2s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 2.3s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 2.4s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 2.5s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 2.6s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 2.7s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 2.8s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 2.9s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 3.0s }


table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 3.1s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 3.2s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 3.3s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 3.4s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 3.5s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 3.6s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 3.7s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 3.8s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 3.9s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 4.0s }

table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 4.1s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 4.2s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 4.3s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 4.4s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 4.5s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 4.6s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 4.7s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 4.8s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 4.9s }
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 5.0s }


table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 5.1s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 5.2s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 5.3s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 5.4s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 5.5s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 5.6s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 5.7s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 5.8s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 5.9s }
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 6.0s }


table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 6.1s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 6.2s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 6.3s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 6.4s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 6.5s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 6.6s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 6.7s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 6.8s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 6.9s }
table tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 7.0s }


table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 7.1s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 7.2s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 7.3s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 7.4s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 7.5s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 7.6s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 7.7s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 7.8s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 7.9s }
table tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 8.0s }


table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 8.1s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 8.2s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 8.3s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 8.4s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 8.5s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 8.6s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 8.7s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 8.8s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 8.9s }
table tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 9.0s }


table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 9.1s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 9.2s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 9.3s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 9.4s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(5) div { transition-delay: 9.5s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(6) div { transition-delay: 9.6s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(7) div { transition-delay: 9.7s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(8) div { transition-delay: 9.8s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(9) div { transition-delay: 9.9s }
table tr:nth-child(10) td:nth-child(10) div { transition-delay: 10.0s }


.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    line-height:50px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
 cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#A40205;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
    transition: 1s;
}

.round-button:hover {
    background:#FB0206;
 width: 80px;
 height:80px;
 transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Projet HTML</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation+.css" type="text/css">
<script src="animation+.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery_v2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<table >
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<button class="round-button" onclick="animation()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out animation-delay in CSS.  If each cell has a proper delay you will likely get the effect you seek.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Can you explain more ?

Comment: No one can help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stripped down version of what I was thinking.  This applies a random color to each cell cascading over about a second from top left to bottom right.  You can augment with whatever your 10 color strategy is and can extend this to 10x10 if you like.  Having done an example, I am not certain now this is the best solution, but it will get you going.  transition-delay is not as mature as animation-delay so you might make 10 animations (one for each of your colors) and use an animation with a delay rather than this transition, but the concept would be similar.

```js
function animation(){
  
  // 10 colors but given this demo is 4x4 only the first 4 are used....
  var colors = [
    "rgb(0,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(100,100,100)",
    "rgb(125,125,125)",
    "rgb(150,150,150)",
    "rgb(175,175,175)",
    "rgb(200,200,200)",
    "rgb(225,225,225)"
  ];
  
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table td div")).forEach(function(item, index){
    // each row gets a color....
    var color = colors[ index % 4 ];
    item.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}
```

```css
body { width: 624px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; line-height: 1; }

table { padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
table td { height: 35px; width: 35px; padding: 0em; background-color:#F7F27F; }
table td div { height:100%; width: 100%; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }

table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#B0090C; }
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) { background-color:#B0090C; }

table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 0.1s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 0.2s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 0.3s }
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 0.4s }

table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 0.5s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 0.6s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 0.7s }
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 0.8s }

table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 0.9s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 1.0s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 1.1s }
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 1.2s }

table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) div { transition-delay: 1.3s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) div { transition-delay: 1.4s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3) div { transition-delay: 1.5s }
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4) div { transition-delay: 1.6s }

.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    line-height:50px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#A40205;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}

.round-button:hover {
    background:#9E2C2E;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<table >
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<button class="round-button"onclick="animation()">Start</button>
```

Comment: **Thanks man** that's cool, **but**, Can you  make the colors change from the first tile to the last ( of the first line ) and then return to the first tile of the  second line and do the same until the end ?

Comment: Thanks so much, very nice

Comment: But @JonSG if i want to add just 10 colors, how can i do that ?

Comment: can you add a picture of what you are looking for?

Comment: I want exactly what you did, But i want 10 colors instead of random color,

Comment: one color in each column, one color in each row, or cells randomly assigned one of the 10?

Comment: The demo has been updated with one color per column.  :-)

Comment: Hey @JonSG , if i add 11 colors, how can i make the transition repeat automatically after the first click on start ?